# Name of the developer on App Store the same of Apple ID?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is the name displayed on the App Store page of an app the same of the Apple ID or it can be changed on iTunes Connect?

For example, if I use my father's Apple ID to publish an app (because I'm under 18), will the name of the developer be mine or his on the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into the [Member Center and select the Your Account tab](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary).  In the Developer Account Summary section is the Name line.  That is what is shown on the App Store for the Company/Organization.

It is not user editable so if it is showing your father's name but you want it under a new company name, you will need to call Apple to ask to have it changed.